# sh/awk (partly) script returning a null value but want it to return a value

Tags: linux, awk, sh

I have the following sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh


function usage(){
echo ""
echo " use like this: cat ../mfshangingsoctelsim.2015-07-28.*.log | ./kevin.sh ms504201"
echo " use one of the following scanners for alh: ms504201 ms503201 ms502201 ms501201"
echo "now exiting..."
exit 1
}


#[[ $# -eq 1 ]] || usage
#[[ $1 == "attack" ]] || usage


date=$(date --date="-2 days" +%F)


clear
echo "==============================================================="
echo "    RED status on BCS loops on $date"
echo "==============================================================="
echo


grep -E 'SCS([0-9]*)_ORDER(_OUTER|)_LOOP' $(ls -tr ../mfsBoxedOutboundService.$date.*.log) |
awk -v scanner="$1" '
begin{
indexx = 0
outerred = 0  # is it time to check all SCS? - 1 yes as OUTER is red
scs01=0;scs02=0;scs03=0;scs04=0;scs05=0;scs07=0;scs08=0;scs09=0;scs10=0
scs11=0;scs12=0;scs13=0;scs14=0;scs15=0;scs17=0;scs18=0;scs19=0;scs20=0
t = 0
tt = 0
}

{
printf($3);
if (match($0,"state=RED")&&match($0,"SCS_ORDER_OUTER_LOOP")&&outerred==0) {scsouterred[indexx]=substr($3,1,8);
                                                                                scsouterbreachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);
                                                                                outerred=1;
                                                                                scs01=1;scs02=1;scs03=1;scs04=1;scs05=1;scs07=1;scs08=1;scs09=1;scs10=1;
                                                                                scs11=1;scs12=1;scs13=1;scs14=1;scs15=1;scs17=1;scs18=1;scs19=1;scs20=1;
                                                                        }

if (outerred==1) {

        if (match($0,"state=GREEN")&&match($0,"SCS_ORDER_OUTER_LOOP")) {scsoutergreen[indexx]=substr($3,1,8);indexx++;outerred=0}

        if (scs01=1&&match($0,"SCS01_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs01breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs01=0;}
        if (scs02=1&&match($0,"SCS02_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs02breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs02=0;}


                        }  # main loop to collect scs levels and wait for green

printf("\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r");
}

END{
print "";print "-------------scs------------------------------------------------";
i = (substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60+(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2))
for (a in scsouterred) {
t = (substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60+(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2))
print scsouterred[a],"-",scsoutergreen[a],"-",t,"min","outer:",scsouterbreachlevel[a],"scs01:",scs01breachlevel[a],"scs02:",scs02breachlevel[a],"scs03:",scs03breachlevel[a],"scs04:",scs04breachlevel[a],"scs05:",scs05breachlevel[a],"scs07:",scs07breachlevel[a],"scs08:",scs08breachlevel[a],"scs09:",scs09breachlevel[a],"scs10:",scs10breachlevel[a],"scs11:",scs11breachlevel[a],"scs12:",scs12breachlevel[a],"scs13:",scs13breachlevel[a],"scs14:",scs14breachlevel[a],"scs15:",scs15breachlevel[a],"scs17:",scs17breachlevel[a],"scs18:",scs18breachlevel[a],"scs19:",scs19breachlevel[a],"scs20:",scs20breachlevel[a];
tt = tt + t;
}
print "total number of incidents: ",indexx," for ",tt," minutes"



}

'
```

the values that it is outputting looks like the following:

```
===============================================================
    RED status on BCS loops on 2015-12-17
===============================================================

23:59:59.969
-------------scs------------------------------------------------
16:08:32 - 16:18:54 - 10 min outer: 550 scs01: 4 scs02: 2 scs03: 5 scs04: 9 scs05: 6 scs07: 7 scs08: 8 scs09: 9 scs10: 6 scs11: 3 scs12: 4 scs13: 24 scs14: 4 scs15: 5 scs17: 7 scs18: 5 scs19: 6 scs20: 9
12:33:15 - 12:36:33 - 3 min outer: 550 scs01: 2 scs02: 9 scs03: 13 scs04: 4 scs05: 8 scs07: 2 scs08: 7 scs09: 7 scs10: 10 scs11: 5 scs12: 6 scs13: 5 scs14: 4 scs15: 6 scs17: 7 scs18: 11 scs19: 11 scs20: 9
16:20:34 - 16:25:44 - 5 min outer: 550 scs01: 8 scs02: 6 scs03: 10 scs04: 7 scs05: 7 scs07: 21 scs08: 0 scs09: 10 scs10: 3 scs11: 3 scs12: 6 scs13: 6 scs14: 3 scs15: 5 scs17: 9 scs18: 4 scs19: 14 scs20: 11
16:41:57 - 16:51:02 - 10 min outer: 550 scs01: 1 scs02: 4 scs03: 8 scs04: 4 scs05: 2 scs07: 0 scs08:  scs09: 8 scs10: 7 scs11: 7 scs12: 8 scs13: 1 scs14: 3 scs15: 1 scs17: 6 scs18: 4 scs19:  scs20: 25
18:22:54 - 18:44:08 - 22 min outer: 550 scs01: 4 scs02: 5 scs03: 9 scs04: 5 scs05: 11 scs07: 1 scs08: 3 scs09: 7 scs10: 13 scs11: 5 scs12: 8 scs13: 4 scs14: 8 scs15: 7 scs17: 10 scs18: 10 scs19: 15 scs20: 9
19:02:09 - 19:08:17 - 6 min outer: 550 scs01: 3 scs02: 5 scs03: 6 scs04: 1 scs05: 6 scs07: 3 scs08: 12 scs09: 3 scs10:  scs11: 1 scs12: 5 scs13: 4 scs14: 6 scs15: 4 scs17: 6 scs18: 2 scs19: 12 scs20: 8
19:28:21 - 19:33:24 - 5 min outer: 551 scs01: 4 scs02: 3 scs03: 5 scs04: 5 scs05: 7 scs07: 1 scs08:  scs09: 0 scs10: 2 scs11: 1 scs12: 1 scs13: 0 scs14: 2 scs15: 4 scs17: 3 scs18: 4 scs19: 17 scs20:
23:19:04 - 23:55:56 - 36 min outer: 550 scs01: 3 scs02: 3 scs03: 6 scs04: 5 scs05: 4 scs07: 4 scs08: 13 scs09: 2 scs10: 7 scs11: 5 scs12: 7 scs13: 7 scs14: 5 scs15: 4 scs17: 2 scs18: 8 scs19: 7 scs20: 9
23:59:05 -  - -1439 min outer: 550 scs01: 1 scs02: 5 scs03: 6 scs04: 5 scs05: 13 scs07: 2 scs08: 11 scs09: 7 scs10: 6 scs11: 3 scs12: 12 scs13: 6 scs14: 4 scs15: 6 scs17: 6 scs18: 7 scs19: 6 scs20: 8
12:39:56 - 12:43:15 - 4 min outer: 550 scs01: 6 scs02: 14 scs03: 14 scs04: 2 scs05: 5 scs07: 5 scs08: 10 scs09: 3 scs10: 11 scs11: 6 scs12: 4 scs13: 7 scs14: 9 scs15: 10 scs17: 3 scs18: 7 scs19: 5 scs20: 9
12:43:38 - 12:48:34 - 5 min outer: 550 scs01: 2 scs02: 1 scs03: 7 scs04: 8 scs05: 7 scs07: 4 scs08: 8 scs09: 4 scs10: 13 scs11: 4 scs12: 3 scs13: 4 scs14: 9 scs15: 7 scs17: 4 scs18: 1 scs19: 3 scs20: 0
12:56:44 - 13:20:07 - 24 min outer: 550 scs01: 1 scs02: 1 scs03: 10 scs04: 6 scs05: 6 scs07: 0 scs08: 6 scs09: 3 scs10: 0 scs11: 1 scs12: 3 scs13: 3 scs14: 4 scs15: 4 scs17: 5 scs18: 2 scs19: 8 scs20: 9
total number of incidents:  11  for  -1309  minutes
```

As you can see it is returning a null value against the following line:

```
23:59:05 -  - -1439 min outer: 550 scs01: 1 scs02: 5 scs03: 6 scs04: 5 scs05: 13 scs07: 2 scs08: 11 scs09: 7 scs10: 6 scs11: 3 scs12: 12 scs13: 6 scs14: 4 scs15: 6 scs17: 6 scs18: 7 scs19: 6 scs20: 8
```

This should look like the lines above and below. 
([time] - [time] - [duration] etc)

Which is in turn effecting the time calculation ( negative number)

I need to put something around the scsoutergreen call to stop it returning a null value. I have tried the following:

```
if [ -n "scsoutergreen[a]" ]; then "23:55:99" fi
```

but this returns a syntax error on if, ] and then.

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `As you can see it is returning a null value` - Really? Not clear to me how or where we're supposed to see that in what you've posted...

Comment: @John3136 I have just updated the post to show the line that is providing a null value. For even more clarity it should look like the lines above and below it. ([time - time - duration etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working.

I did the following:

```
#!/bin/sh


function usage(){
echo ""
echo " use like this: cat ../mfshangingsoctelsim.2015-07-28.*.log | ./kevin.sh ms504201"
echo " use one of the following scanners for alh: ms504201 ms503201 ms502201 ms501201"
echo "now exiting..."
exit 1
}


#[[ $# -eq 1 ]] || usage
#[[ $1 == "attack" ]] || usage



date=$(date --date="-1 days" +%F)


clear
echo "==============================================================="
echo "    RED status on BCS loops on $date"
echo "==============================================================="
echo


grep -E 'SCS([0-9]*)_ORDER(_OUTER|)_LOOP' $(ls -tr ../mfsBoxedOutboundService.$date.*.log) |
awk -v scanner="$1" '
begin{
indexx = 0
outerred = 0  # is it time to check all SCS? - 1 yes as OUTER is red
scs01=0;scs02=0;scs03=0;scs04=0;scs05=0;scs07=0;scs08=0;scs09=0;scs10=0
scs11=0;scs12=0;scs13=0;scs14=0;scs15=0;scs17=0;scs18=0;scs19=0;scs20=0
t = 0
tt = 0
}

{
printf($3);
if (match($0,"state=RED")&&match($0,"SCS_ORDER_OUTER_LOOP")&&outerred==0) {scsouterred[indexx]=substr($3,1,8);
                                                                                scsouterbreachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);
                                                                                outerred=1;
                                                                                scs01=1;scs02=1;scs03=1;scs04=1;scs05=1;scs07=1;scs08=1;scs09=1;scs10=1;
                                                                                scs11=1;scs12=1;scs13=1;scs14=1;scs15=1;scs17=1;scs18=1;scs19=1;scs20=1;
                                                                        }

if (outerred==1) {

        if (match($0,"state=GREEN")&&match($0,"SCS_ORDER_OUTER_LOOP")) {scsoutergreen[indexx]= substr($3,1,8);indexx++;outerred=0}

        if (scs01=1&&match($0,"SCS01_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs01breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs01=0;}
        if (scs02=1&&match($0,"SCS02_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs02breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs02=0;}
        if (scs03=1&&match($0,"SCS03_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs03breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs03=0;}
        if (scs04=1&&match($0,"SCS04_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs04breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs04=0;}
        if (scs05=1&&match($0,"SCS05_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs05breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs05=0;}
        if (scs07=1&&match($0,"SCS07_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs07breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs07=0;}
        if (scs08=1&&match($0,"SCS08_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs08breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs08=0;}
        if (scs09=1&&match($0,"SCS09_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs09breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs09=0;}
        if (scs10=1&&match($0,"SCS10_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs10breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs10=0;}
        if (scs11=1&&match($0,"SCS11_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs11breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs11=0;}
        if (scs12=1&&match($0,"SCS12_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs12breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs12=0;}
        if (scs13=1&&match($0,"SCS13_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs13breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs13=0;}

        if (scs14=1&&match($0,"SCS14_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs14breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs14=0;}
        if (scs15=1&&match($0,"SCS15_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs15breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs15=0;}
        if (scs17=1&&match($0,"SCS17_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs17breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs17=0;}
        if (scs18=1&&match($0,"SCS18_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs18breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs18=0;}
        if (scs19=1&&match($0,"SCS19_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs19breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs19=0;}
        if (scs20=1&&match($0,"SCS20_ORDER_LOOP")) {scs20breachlevel[indexx]=substr($0,index($0,"occupancy=")+10,index($0,"]>")-index($0,"occupancy=")-10);scs20=0;}

                        }  # main loop to collect scs levels and wait for green

printf("\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r");
}

END{
print "";print "-------------scs------------------------------------------------";
i = (substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60+(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2))
for (a in scsouterred) {
if (((substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60)<=0&&(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2))<=0) {t = 0} #start of t = if
else if (((substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60)<= 0) {t = (0+(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2)))}
else if ((substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2))<= 0) {t = (((substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60)+0)}
else {t = ((substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60+(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2)))} #end of t = if
print scsouterred[a],"-",scsoutergreen[a],"-",t,"min","outer:",scsouterbreachlevel[a],"scs01:",scs01breachlevel[a],"scs02:",scs02breachlevel[a],"scs03:",scs03breachlevel[a],"scs04:",scs04breachlevel[a],"scs05:",scs05breachlevel[a],"scs07:",scs07breachlevel[a],"scs08:",scs08breachlevel[a],"scs09:",scs09breachlevel[a],"scs10:",scs10breachlevel[a],"scs11:",scs11breachlevel[a],"scs12:",scs12breachlevel[a],"scs13:",scs13breachlevel[a],"scs14:",scs14breachlevel[a],"scs15:",scs15breachlevel[a],"scs17:",scs17breachlevel[a],"scs18:",scs18breachlevel[a],"scs19:",scs19breachlevel[a],"scs20:",scs20breachlevel[a];
tt = tt + t;
}
print "total number of incidents: ",indexx," for ",tt," minutes \r\r"
print "-----NOTE-----\r"
print "If time is empty recovery was after 23:59:99 on ",$3

}

'
```

The changes I made from the original is that I modified the setting of the t variable in the lower half of the script from:

```
t = (substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60+(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2))
```

To the following:

```
if (((substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60)<=0&&(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2))<=0) {t = 0} #start of t = if
else if (((substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60)<= 0) {t = (0+(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2)))}
else if ((substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2))<= 0) {t = (((substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60)+0)}
else {t = ((substr(scsoutergreen[a],1,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],1,2))*60+(substr(scsoutergreen[a],4,2)-substr(scsouterred[a],4,2)))}
```

This resolves the null time issue and returns a 0 if the time works out to be <= 0 or the actual calculation if it isn't.

Comment: `begin` is an unset variable so your whole subsequent block is not being executed, which is fine since it's not doing anything useful, but you probably meant the awk keyword `BEGIN`. Your script has several other issues, I highly recommend you read the book Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. It also has shell errors, which the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson could help with, and general programming issues (e.g. performing the same op multiple times in if-elses) which unfortunately I think only some kind of programming class could help with.